# visual studio compiler?

Tags: c++, windows, winmain

i try to complete [this](http://johnnie.jerrata.com/winsocktutorial/#creatingalisteningsocket) tutorial, but i don't know what VS 2008 project to use for it, as everything that i tried gave me either a `error C2731: 'wWinMain' : function cannot be overloaded` error (for a Win32 project where i change the `APIENTRY _tWinMain()` with `WINAPI WinMain()` method from the tutorial), 
or many errors like `error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _closesocket@4 referenced in function _WinMain@16`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quote from the same tutorial:

> Remember that any code presented in this tutorial **should be linked with the Winsock library, usually wsock32.lib or something similarly named.** Also, when using code exactly as presented in the tutorial in your own IDE (Dev-C++, Microsoft VC++, C++ Builder, etc.), choose to build a Windows project with a WinMain() to avoid errors.

To accomplish this use either:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "wsock32.lib")
```

in your source file (doesn't matter much which), or add it to the Project Linker options.

Also note that [according to the latest MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737582%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), the correct library name is `Ws2_32.lib`.